# NuGet / MSBuild not copying binaries to local output folder without HintPath

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have edited Global nuget.config to use a single package folder.

I have a new blank C# console project created by VS2015. I add a NuGet reference, for example Newtonsoft.Json, then VS creates a packages.config and lists Newtonsoft.Json as a package.

This gets added to the .csproj file.

`<Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\CxCache\Newtonsoft.Json.9.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>`

When building the project, Newtonsoft.Json binaries are copied into local bin folder. If I delete the Newtonsoft.Json dll from local bin, it will be recopied after a build.

However I don't want to use HintPath property in csproj (don't want to check into repo) so I figure, I should be able to delete HintPath and it'll work fine. I remove the HintPath line from .csproj and delete Newtonsoft.Json dll from local bin.

This time upon build, Newtonsoft.Json binaries from global nuget package folder is not copied to local bin. Is there a work around?

Comment: Usually you'd use "restore packages on build" to avoid checking NuGets in... (clearly not an answer to your question, but probably what you should do instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Bin* folder (*TargetDir*) - the folder to which you build, should not be part of your source control. You NEED *HintPath* because without it, IDE will first check GAC, and then it will check *TargetDir*, and then it will check ... it may find Newtonsoft dll of completely different version somewhere on your drive, the wrong file.

You need to correct the setup you have - do not check in any bin folders into source control, ever. You should have branch structure and have *packages* folder under your branch and all solutions in your branch can work with it. You can check in your entire *packages* folder so that solution doesn't need to download every time - this is ok. But never check in output. See - *HintPath* can contain relative path so that you go with your structure anywhere you want. Tomorrow you can move your branch into different location in source control and your relative path will remain valid. Definitely - you need *HintPath*

Comment: Thanks a lot for that. That much i understand. However the reason why I don't want a hintpath is that the other people using this repo will have their own global packages location. So what Visual Studio enters as HintPath may only be valid for me. I'm just wondering why NuGet can't look at packages.config and check global packages folder.

Comment: @AndrewPham When you building your project/solution, nuget is not involved. It is IDE/msbuild trying to establish reference location. Project file is a compilation instruction. If you and other developers working from different points - this is problem. All developers must (that is if you want to have good life), must have same code structure. If you're talking of some sort storage location for compiled code - use network folder and use post-build event to copy content of targetdir to that location.

Comment: In the VS experience you can get it to download a nuget package into a global folder, have copied into targetdir  and have a entry into packages.config all in one click. Is it really impossible for there to be a reverse of that without HintPath. By reading packages.config to find the required binaries and using nuget.config to find global folder location it could then do as it did before, download the nuget package (or not if it is already there) and copy into targetdir?

Comment: Hey man nvm i just realized that, what I'm looking for is for MSBuild and Nuget to join functionality which is unlikely for several reasons. One being what if I don't want to use NuGet as the package manager and only MSBuild to build.

Comment: @AndrewPham Look, I am a build master of very large and complex code based. I architect the whole setup. We have no issue. You understand that really, best way - you download nuget stuff, check it in, so it becomes your code base. MsBuild is driven by project files. You tell the configuration to build. system Dlls don't have HintPath because VS and MSbuild programmed to find correct framework. But for 3rd party dependencies it is different. MsBuild can only trigger get nuget because it is part of solution. But this is project file that drives compilation. See my answers on build architecture